# Проблема работы с while

Tags: python, while

```
i = 0
number = 0
while number <= 99:
    number += 1
while 1 == 1:
    i += 1
    print("вика) меЛник взламывает казино.")
    print("Выкачано бабла: " + str(i) + " грн.")
    print("Казино взломано на " + str(number) + "%.")
    if i == 30000:
        break
print("вика) меЛник задолбалась цыганить бабки. До связи.")
input("Press ENTER to exit.")
```

Недавно начал изучать циклы в Python'е. Написал вот такое простой код, но проблема в том, что на каждой строке пишет "Казино взламывается на 100%", а я хочу, чтобы, на каждый 1 процент взлома приходилось 300 грн. на 2 процент 600, и т.д. до 30000 грн, и чтобы при этом, скрипт не начинал сразу с 300 грн, и потом перепрыгивал на 600, а чтобы так же проходил цикл с 10, 50, 100, 200 гривнами и т.д, а потом уже когда скрипт дойдёт до 300 грн. - должен появиться 1%.

То есть хочу получить что-то вроде этого:
"вика) взламывает казино.
Выкачано бабла: 100 грн.
Казино взломано на 0%.
...
вика) взламывает казино.
Выкачано бабла: 300 грн.
Казино взломано на 1%."
И так далее пока цикл не дойдёт до 30000 грн.
Извиняюсь за столь глупую программу, просто хочется таким образом посмеяться вместе с друзьями...)

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/LoudBlaringBits#main.py

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
while 1 == 1:
    i += 1
    print("вика) меЛник взламывает казино.")
    print("Выкачано бабла: " + str(i) + " грн.")
    percent = str (i / 300)
    if i % 10 == 0 and i != 30000:
        print("Казино взломано на {:.1}".format(percent) + "%.")
    if i == 30000:
        break
print("вика) меЛник задолбалась цыганить бабки. До связи.")
input("Press ENTER to exit.")
```